# How to restrict registration and create own sign up in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In Devise we can restrict user to sign up directly by removing :registerable symbol form User model. But my theme is to create own user sign up page and controller and allow admin to create users manually. I tried many times but the problem is that how to encrypt password so that it becomes accessible by devise during login. If there is any idea please help.

Comment: dont remove signup module

Comment: But I want admin only to create user which is not possible with login. If I'm logged in it redirects to root_path informing that you are already logged in. Is there any idea ? @uzaif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did this for solving problem**

1. I just deleted the :registerable form user model
2. Then manually create a user controller and form for creating data.
3. Then set necessary validation in user model.
4. When submitting data the user model automatically encrypted and saved password.

**And thank you for effort for helping**.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions and solution:

1. Don't delete the `:regesterable` from `User` model. Instead, just define a different **route** for the `registration` in `routes.rb` file, so that others cannot find that path to register.
   e.g. `devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_up: 'register_not_allowed' }`
2. Create a **module** like `Admin` and then define a **controller** like `UsersController` under this module. e.g.

   `module Admin
     class UsersController < ApplicationController
     end
   end`
3. In the `controller` create **new**, **edit**, **show**, **create**, **update** methods as you do for any controller. create a form having fields with `email`, `password`, `password_confirmation` and also with the additional fields which is an attribute in `User` model. Then require them in the strong parameters of your `admin/users` controller. Now when you create an user using this form no encryption of password is needed.

**app/views/admin/users/_form.html.erb**

`<%= form_for [:admin, @user]  do |f| %>
<% end %>`